# laggy animations and scrolling

Tags: jquery, performance, css

I have a problem with website performance. Here are links:

[first](http://www.rafalfundakowski.pl/newsitemain/index4.html)

[second](http://www.rafalfundakowski.pl/aneta/aneta1.html)

First one performance is almost unacceptable in firefox and extremly laggy in opera. Second one is not so complex, but performace is not good eighter. I'm trying to make css as clean as possible and I'm making JS based on tutorials and tricks that are working fine. I run both on YSlow but got A for everything execpt not using CDN, expireheaders and image sprites- but these element mainly influence the reqests time, am I right? Can it be caused by excesive amount of box-shadow? I'm feeling like I'm missing something important but basic.

If you don't want to click on external links and require a fiddle, let me know, I will make one.

Comment: your images are very big in size just reduce the size and see,http://www.rafalfundakowski.pl/newsitemain/p3.jpg size also use a cdn for delivering static contents

Comment: Thanks, but thats not it. I changed every image on site to small placeholder and even when I open page from my computer it's extremly laggy in opera

Comment: I have to mention one more thing- these pages have a lot of exanding box problem- since I'm to planing to make it IE6 compatible, I wasn't fixing it. May it cause performance problems?